# Packer Template incorrectly pre-pending EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

A prefix of ec2 is being added in the packer AMI bake job which is causing some issues as we need the URL to be ebs-fips.us-east-1.amazonaws.com as per FIPS - Amazon Web Services (AWS) but currently is coming through as below:

amazon-ebs: error validating regions: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://ec2.fips.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp: lookup ec2.fips.us-east-1.amazonaws.com no such host

What would be the best way to remove the ec2 prefix?

Answer (score 1):

By adding the following custom_endpoint_ec2 to your builders should resolve the issue

```
"custom_endpoint_ec2" : "https://ec2-fips.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
```

HashiCorp Reference: https://www.packer.io/plugins/builders/amazon/ebsvolume#custom_endpoint_ec2